# Specific button pre selected - HTML Thymeleaf

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I have an java object **Product** that has a String field called setup.

Due to the setting the behavior is different.

I want the the user can decide at runtime how the object behaves.

At the moment the user receives a view with all the current information but since the setup is a select-button I don't know how I can tell Thymeleaf/HTML to show the current setup value to be selected in the optionbox first.

For example: It would be great if the current setup in the object is "Medium" or "Low" or "High" that this will be selected and show in the option box to the user first. Currently "Auto" is always the first choice to be shown no matter what state is in the object.

[image]

Is it possible what I want? I am very new to HTML and Thymeleaf. If it's a bit more to do and a new technologie please try to tell me step by step how to make this working :) (I have no clue about css, java-script etc)

Thank you very much. I use SpringBoot with MVC, Thymleaf, Bootstrap and [Bootstrap-select.](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#limit-the-number-of-selections)

```
        <tbody>
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="productList" type="java.util.List"*/-->
        <tr th:each="product : ${productList}">
            <!--/*@thymesVar id="name" type="java.lang.String"*/-->
            <td th:text="${product.getProductName()}"></td>
            <td th:text="${price}"></td>
            <td><input type="number" th:placeholder="'Current: '+  *{product.getBottom()}"  name="bottom"/></td>
            <td><label><select name="setup" class="selectpicker show-tick" data-width="fit">
                <option>Auto</option>
                <option>High</option>
                <option>Medium</option>
                <option>Low</option>
            </select></label>
            </td>
            <td><label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" value=""/></label></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to set the default selected option in a select box. Try something like:

```xml
<option th:selected="${product.setup == 'Medium'}">Medium</option>
```

Comment: Yes true. But I is not always medium, it can be also Auto, Low or High.

Comment: @AnnaKlein Repeat the pattern for the other options _or_ put a list of all options in the model and loop it with `th:each`.